# How can I calculate mean for all columns in a dataframe using dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, data-manipulation

I am trying to calculate mean value for all columns in a dataframe using dplyr. currently I am using the following code. It does not work. Change the last line to use "summarise_" or to use "mean(as.name(cln))" does not fix it either. 
I can not use the dev version of dplyr because of a bug in devtools :(

```
for (cln in colnames(log))
{
  if(is.numeric(log[,cln])){
    gd <- log %>% 
      group_by(groups) %>%
      summarise(mean_value = mean(cln))
}}
```

Comment: Hi can you give an example of your data please?

Comment: Hi @Frost_maggot . The data is a table "groups" are factors. other columns are measure data for some user, for each user I have a row.

Comment: I end up using summarise_each() for my purpose. However, the last line of aboving code still does not work.